# What do I do with this pile of branches, collected from pruning?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, mulch

After pruning my trees I piled up branches and I was thinking of shredding these with some wood shredder and using them as mulch. But unfortunately there is no  shredder nearby this village and I can't do it. My options are:

1. Get rid of them (Burn them).
2. leave them until I find a shredder or chipper to hire.(But maybe these pile will bring infections or other things to my garden).
3. You tell me please.
   [image]

Comment: where are you at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a branch pile you can do many things including:

- leave them to provide cover for animals
- grow mushrooms in them letting them grow good there
- burn them
- make biochar with them
- dig a pit to provide a cool spot for water to come up through Based upon where you're at I highly suggest doing this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xcZS7arcgk

Comment: Thank you I am from Miyaneh, East Azerbaijan of Iran. It is a small city. the village name is Avenliq. So leaving theme there is not detrimental for garden?

Answer (score 0):

They will decompose in a few years.  I have such a pile behind the house.  It gets built up to about 5 feet each year, and drops to about 3 a year later.  This is in a fairly dry climate with below freezing temperatures for 6 months of the year.  In warmer, wetter climates decomposition will be faster.  In colder or drier climates decomposition will be slower.

You can speed it up by adding finer cut material (lawn clippings, weeds) that help retain moisture.  The bigger branches take a long time.

Comment: you didn't take in local environmental conditions.